# being called but not drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have some code in the `drawRect:` method that draws a series of circles from an array. I can verify that the points stay in memory long enough and get to the point where they should be drawn. However, it seems as if the `fill` method of `NSBezierPath` is not drawing the circles.

Here is my `drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSPoint aPoint;
    NSRect aRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 6, 6);

    // Erase the rectangle
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);

    // Draw the dots
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(77.0/255.0) green:(11.0/255.0) blue:(11.0/255.0) alpha:1.0] set];

    for(NSValue *aValuePoint in arrayOfPoints) {
        aPoint = [aValuePoint pointValue];
        aRect.origin.y = aPoint.y - aRect.size.height/2.0;
        aRect.origin.x = aPoint.x - aRect.size.width/2.0;

        // The code does get to this point, it does not draw however...
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRect] fill];
    }
}
```

I have another method `drawDotAtPoint:` where I add the points to an array

```
- (void)drawDotAtPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    NSLog(@"drawDotAtPoint:(%f, %f)", aPoint.x, aPoint.y);
    [arrayOfPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:aPoint]];

    // I've also tried using [self superview] instead of just self        
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

And while I am able to verify that these methods are called at the correct times (or so it seems) no drawing after the initial drawRect: will take place

Sidenote:
My goal is to actually draw a point and have a ring appear around it, enlarge and fade out. Much similar to the GPS current location indicator on iOS, in the Maps app. Any insight on that would also be appreciated.

Comment: This code works perfectly for me...how are you creating your view?

Comment: I'm setting it as the contentView of a window: [self setContentView:[[VisualEventView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self contentView] frame]]];

Comment: Still working for me...what does `[self canDraw]` say inside of the for loop? Also, two notes: I don't think `clearColor` does what you think it does -- it's transparent (you might want [`NSEraseRect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSEraseRect)); and as a matter of style/convention, your method shouldn't start with `draw...` if it doesn't actually do any drawing.

Comment: `[self canDraw]` returns `YES`, and as per your request I have changed the API to `placeDotAtPoint:`. I know about this convention I had just forgotten to change the method name as it was originally intended to actually draw the dots. Thanks for the tip about `NSEraseRect`, but it fills the rectangle with white and I need it to be completely transparent with nothing drawn on it.

Comment: Oh, yes, from reading your comment below I understand why you want it to be transparent. So this is a sort of overlay on your WebView, and you've got it in a transparent, borderless window? I've set all that up, and it's still working for me 100%. Take a look at the code I just posted and see if anything jumps out at you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your points and make sure that you don't have an inverted rectangle and that your X/Y coords are what you expect.  Make sure that your anchor point and coordinates are correctly relative.

You may be helped along a bit by using a tool called Quartz Debug that comes with apple's developer tools.  It is in the /Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools/ folder.  After starting this tool, go to the "tools" menu and turn on "Flash Screen Updates".  This will give you an idea of when things are being redrawn or not.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: FWIW, 0,0 is bottom-left on the Mac (unless the parent's coordinate space is flipped), and top-left on iOS.

Comment: (0,0) is bottom left unless `[myView isFlipped]`

Comment: yes--in CoreAnimation (0,0) is top left. In AppKit (0,0) is bottom left, unless [myView isFlipped].

Comment: Thanks for the clarification all, I had assumed this was in a core animation context, but that may be a bad assumption.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help much. I am drawing in a window that is placed on top of a WebView as a child window of the WebView-containing window (I had to resort to this because you can't place views on top of a WebView). I am also able to confirm that I am able to draw outside of the for...in loop, even though the array has elements and is being looped through.

Comment: **No**, the default origin is lower left on Mac OS X, [regardless of Core Animation usage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW8). @neilsbot

Comment: I must be thinking of iOS then...  I swear I had to deal with that when imaging for printing at one point though, maybe it was in a different context.  Thanks for the link Josh.

Comment: Text views use upper-left as origin, so if you were printing text, that's probably what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I've copy-pasted your view code. I stuck this in an app delegate for testing. `BadView` is the custom view here (no reflection on you -- "Bad" because it's misbehaving `:)` ) The windows are both created in IB, and the WebView is likewise placed in the parent window in IB.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // badWindow is an IBOutlet to the overlay window, parentWindow an IBOutlet
    // to the window with the webview, myWebView an IBOutlet to the webview
    BadView * myBadView = [[BadView alloc] initWithFrame:[[badWindow contentView] frame]];
    // Create some random points for testing
    [myBadView createArrayOfPoints];


    [badWindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [badWindow setOpaque:NO];
    [badWindow setAlphaValue:0.9];    // Will still act opaque without this
    [badWindow setHasShadow:NO];
    [badWindow setContentView:myBadView];

    [parentWindow addChildWindow:badWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]]];

    [myBadView release];
}
```

Comment: I tried the code, I did however move the code to `awakeFromNib` as the windows are created in a XIB file. It still does not draw, although the rest works as expected, so I am unsure of what is causing this problem...

Comment: I just added a modified version of the code to create windows, webviews, and show windows to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. I confirm that it calls `drawRect:` and adds points and that `drawRect:` receives them, but they are still not drawn. Could it be a bug in the XCode/llvm compilation process. (I am running XCode 4)

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumped. Note that I _am_ creating the windows in the xib. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful...

Comment: I have seemed to figure it out. I'm not sure why what I wrote just now is working and the above code wasn't... Oh well, I guess it's just one of those things.